# How to retain LCD brightness after reboot

Tags: brightness

I frequently test different linux Distros and recently found a 'feature' that I would like to know how to turn on in Ubuntu. In my testing of Fedora 20 I noticed that it retained the LCD brightness settings on my laptop after a reboot. Ubuntu 13.10 nor 14.04 does this.

The laptop in question is a Lenovo T530. Does anyone know why/how Fedora (Gnome 3.10) does this? Can it be replicated in Ubuntu?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how this is done in Fedora, but to do this in Ubuntu:

First know the output name

```
xrandr -q
```

for example my output name is DVI-I-2

The brightness can be changed like this:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-2 --brightness 1
```

Now add this command to your startup programs or to the /etc/rc.local file.

Comment: With Fedora 20 I can use the brightness keys on the laptop and then on reboot the computer starts at the previous brightness. I suspect that this would not work in that manner.

Comment: Indeed, this would only work for a fixed brightness setting. What  OP (and me) seems to look for is persistent brightness setting across reboots.